# How do I tell cmake to output to a target architecture folder?

Tags: c++, cmake

Basically, I want CMake to generate a folder depending on the target architecture that I am building for in both the library folder and the bin folder. I.e. My project structure looks like:

```
src/
    a.cpp
    b.cpp
lib/
bin/
```

And I want the result of CMake to be as follows:

```
src/
    a.cpp
    b.cpp
lib/
    i686-w64-mingw32/
        project.a
bin/
    i686-w64-mingw32/
        project.exe
```

Where `gcc -dumpmachine` produced `i686-w64-mingw32` (but ideally this would work for all compilation flows including visual studio and xcode).

Comment: I store GCC dumpmachine into a bash variable and build through a script, passing in this value to cmake's install directory through CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX (edit: I do the same for building out of the source directory by changing the current working directory to a build folder with the arch name, I think through -B flag which is somewhat undocumented)

Comment: but that wont work for win32 + mac where I'm using vs + xcode to compile respectively (more specifically it wont change for 32/64 bit builds) :(

Comment: yeah I have scripts for each platform to launch the cmake stuff because I also cross compile for Android, ios, osx, Linux, windows, on multiple bit architectures, I specifically build one architecture and append it to this name. if you come across a better solution I'm very interested, I hate this one, honestly (edit: all of them have to be able to be compiled headlessly for me due to build servers)

Comment: But what is wrong in storing output of gcc into **CMake** variable via `execute_process()` and then using this variable in *DESTINATION* option for `install()` commands?

Comment: @Tsyvarev this solution only works if you dont change the architecture from visual studio or xcode after you've generated the project

Comment: @kirinthos I hope theres a better one :(

Comment: I know this has been asked quite a long time ago, but another option is the CMake variable CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE.html), that is often set by the linker.